# How to monitor other process's network io?

Tags: networking, io, monitor

How can I know other process's network io detail by process id?
For example, a special process request http://www.stackoverflow.com by http get method?

Comment: This is a very OS-dependant question, please edit your question to include operating system information.

Comment: thanks kingsley, the operations system is linux~

Comment: Did you consider parsing the output of the `netstat` command ?  E.g.: `netstat | grep 'http'`

Comment: Hi kingsley,  netstat output is too simple, i want to monitor all http io in a special process, such as 'HTTP 1.1 GET /user/get  response something...' thanks~